# How to place certain third party tag on the web page using DTM (at specific location)?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I was trying to put one snippet of third party code on the web page using Dynamic Tag Manager (of Site Catalyst). But the challenge I am facing in doing so is, I want to place this snippet just before closing of the `Body` tag of the page.

I tried most of the combination in Page load rule. Firing rule at `Top of Page` , `Bottom of Page`, loading snippet using `Non-Sequential HTML`, then `Sequential HTML`. But nothing worked out.

Can someone please help me out in finding out how to do it. And how do I verify this on the web page that where exactly the snippet is getting loaded.

Thanks,
Adwait

Comment: Are you placing content? A marketing pixel? Is it meant to be seen? Why do you want it before the closing body tag?

Comment: Yes right Brett, this is a marketing pixel and this pixel was given to us from one of our partner agency with this instruction that this has to be placed just before the closing of the body tag. And hence the requirement.

By the way, is it possible for the pixel to be seen on the page ? As per my understanding, DTM places all the tags on it container and then it renders on the page as per load order rule. Please correct me if I am wrong, I always wanted to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make DTM physically place the snippet of code just before the closing `</body>` tag (though you can write your own code in a DTM custom code container that appends as last child to `body` but that's not really the same thing).

In general, when a vendor asks that their tag be placed just before the closing body tag, it is to make sure everything else on the page has been loaded (so that it does not make your user experience suffer if their code runs slow or fails to load), and/or also to ensure other things on the page are exposed (e.g. if script depends on grabbing values from other things on the page).

If you have properly implemented the DTM tag itself, the **Footer Code** should be just before the closing `</body>` tag already. Then, when you create a **Page Load Rule** and specify it to be triggered at "Bottom of Page", the rule will be triggered when the **Footer Code** is executed, effectively putting it down there at the closing `</body>` tag.

If your container **Type** is "Non-Sequential HTML" then DTM outputs the code as an `iframe`, which is rarely useful.  "Sequential HTML" type  will use `document.write()` to output the content synchronously. This should have been fine for your needs, though depending on your 3rd party script, it would probably be better to do sequential js or probably even non-sequential js, because most 3rd party tags just ask you to place at bottom of page to make sure they aren't interfering with your other site's stuff and most 3rd party scripts themselves load asynchronously.

So, if by "not working" you just mean you don't see it showing up exactly before closing `</body>` tag, I think you're probably fine just outputting at page bottom, though I can't 100% verify that without knowing more details about what it is you are wanting to output.

Beyond that, if "not working" means the script itself isn't working (e.g. loading or working as intended) then you're going to have to provide more info, e.g. what script you are using, what it is supposed to be doing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page load rule that fires at page bottom.  Add a 3rd party script with type Sequential JavaScript.  This will use document.write to include your code at the _satellite.pageBottom() function, which should be placed just before the closing body tag.  That should get you what you need.